# For HTML datetime-local input, can i split their limits to date and time individually?

Tags: html, datetime, datetime-format

```
<input type="datetime-local" min="2020-12-20T10:00" max="2020-12-25T10:00">
```

Hi guys, i am trying to split the min and max values for date and time, for example, 2020 Dec 10 to 2020 Dec 15, 10am-8pm on all of these aforementioned dates. How can I do that? Can i do so without splitting into 2 input types? Thanks